# How to access child element using @XmlElement with Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have a table:

```
table:
    id
    name
    phone-area
    phone-number
```

This XML

```
<person>
    ...

    <phone>
        <area>111</area>
        <number>123-4567</number>
    </phone>

</person>
```

and this code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "person", schema = "test")
public class UserLinkedIn {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    // ...

    @XmlElement(name = "area")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="phone")
    @Column(name = "phone-area")
    double area; 

    @XmlElement(name = "number")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="phone")
    @Column(name = "phone-number")
    double number;
}
```

But when I run it i get this error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
@XmlElementWrapper is only allowed on a collection property but "com.myproject.user.person" is not a collection property.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper(namespace=##default, name=phone, required=false, nillable=false)
```

I thought the "wrapper" annotation will take care of the wrapper element to get the child value. Am i missing something?

** I cannot change the schema nor the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I had to create another class "phone" and map the values to each elements

so in my main class:

```
@Transient
@XmlElement(name = "phone")
private Phone phone;
```

Then in my new class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "phone")
static class Phone {
    @XmlElement(name = "area")
    @Column(name = "area")
    int area;
    @XmlElement(name = "number")
    @Column(name = "number")
    int number;

    // here area = 111
    // pnumber = 123-4567
}
```